# Batch File to set first 3 octets of an IP Range and then prompt user for the last octet...then bring both together to set the IP address

Tags: batch-file

I have been working on a batch file to setup computers at different locations.

At the start of the batch i'd like to set the first 3 octets of the IP Range if required which saves to a text file.

I currently use:

```
cls & set /p IPRANGE=Please Type the first 3 octets of the IP Range for example 10.202.204:
Echo %IPRANGE% > %~d0\StagingTool\iprange.txt
Notepad %~d0\StagingTool\iprange.txt
```

Then each machine i'm setting up requires the last octet entering by the user...

I've tried the following:

```
set /p LASTOCT=Please type in the last Octet for example .41 :
set /p PUSHLASTOCT=%LASTOCT% >%~d0\StagingTool\lastip.txt
set /p FIRST3=<%~d0\StagingTool\IPRANGE.txt
set /p LAST1=<%~d0\StagingTool\LASTIP.txt
set /p FINALIP=%FIRST3%%LAST1% >%~d0\StagingTool\FINALIP.txt
set /p INSERTIP=<%~d0\StagingTool\FINALIP.txt
set /p SUBNET=<%~d0\StagingTool\subnet.txt
set /p GATEWAY=<%~d0\StagingTool\gateway.txt
netsh interface ip set address name="Wi-Fi" static %INSERTIP% %subnet% %gateway% & echo.
```

As you can see from the above i'm attempting to pull the first 3 octets and the last octet together to form the final IP.

In the FINALIP.txt i'm getting a space in between the two inputs for example 192.168.1 .35 which means the IPV4 address is not valid when running the set address.

Any ideas how this can fixed or better accomplished?

Thanks!

Comment: Here's an example of one of the issues: you are `Echo`ing `%IPRANGE%[SPACE]` to `%~d0\StagingTool\iprange.txt`, perhaps removing the unrequired space character would help you, e.g. `(Echo %IPRANGE%)>"%~d0\StagingTool\iprange.txt"`. Might I also suggest that you use doublequotes wherever possible, and please take a look at the output from `Set /?` as you appear to be using the `/P` option despite it not always being required.

Comment: Thanks for noticing that space all working now !

Comment: Consider accepting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are `echo`ing a space with the command `Echo %IPRANGE% > %~d0\StagingTool\iprange.txt` which needs to be removed. You can write:

```bat
echo %IPRANGE%>%~d0\StagingTool\iprange.txt
```

or:

```bat
echo %IPRANGE%> %~d0\StagingTool\iprange.txt
```

or even easier:

```bat
(echo %IPRANGE%)>%~d0\StagingTool\iprange.txt
```